# Responsive image with Bootstrap and mapify jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a highlight feature to my responsive image map. I am using [mapify](http://etiennemartin.ca/mapify/) to add an overlay. I have a responsive image with width = 100% inside a Bootstrap column and I don't know how to get this plugin working, because as long as I understand, it requires the image to have a fixed width and height. How can I solve this problem? The image width should be dependent on the column width.

My code:

```
<div id="torso">
    <img src="../img/symptomenchecker/mf.png" id="torso-image" width="100%" usemap="#male-front-map">
    <map name="male-front-map" id="male-front-map">
        <area shape="poly" id="male-front-head-area" coords="854,269,866,272,898,205,897,165,885,160,867,178,877,119,867,73,833,31,791,10,755,0,712,2,668,20,625,55,610,97,608,138,618,181,599,160,588,161,585,186,592,222,611,271,627,270,629,297,650,324,682,360,706,380,739,389,769,384,813,347,848,311,853,292" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="849,310,844,409,910,444,981,476,1011,484,743,544,475,483,547,461,579,437,639,410,636,308,660,333,687,364,718,384,747,387,781,379">
    </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified width and height must match the native size of the image. 
A quick fix would be to add the following to your css:

```
.mapify-imgHolder .mapify {
    width: 9999px;
}
```